# power bi Dividing the count value by 20

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have the following dax formula i need this formulas value to be divided to 20. As is the formula works good, i couldn't figure out to add in division to it. I appreciate any help

dax Capital_occurrance = CALCULATE(count('Price&Load'[Capital Spreads]),filter('Price&Load','Price&Load'[Capital Spreads]))

Comment: Do you want to divide the count by 20 or divide it into 20 places?

Answer (score 0):

This don't work?

```
Capital_occurrance = CALCULATE(
    count('Price&Load'[Capital Spreads]),
    filter('Price&Load','Price&Load'[Capital Spreads])
) / 20
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's best to use the Divide function when Dividing to avoid dividing by zero.

```
dax Capital_occurrance =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( 'Price&Load'[Capital Spreads] ),
        FILTER ( 'Price&Load', 'Price&Load'[Capital Spreads] )
    ),
    20,
    1
)
```